# Split by excel conditions

Tags: java, regex

I want to split this string:

`=IF(BI18=0;INT(YEAR(TODAY()));IF(INT(YEAR(BI18))>2025;2025;INT(YEAR(BI18))))`

```
[IF, BI18=0, INTYEARTODAY, IF, INTYEARBI18>2025,  2025, INTYEARBI18]
```

I tried it with that regex:

`String[] result = text.substring(1, text.length()).split("[;()]+");`

However, I am getting:

`[IF, BI18=0, INT, YEAR, TODAY, IF, INT, YEAR, BI18, >2025, 2025, INT, YEAR, BI18]`

I am struggeling to identify the excel methods generically.

I would appreciate your answer, to split the string generically as expected.

Comment: You actually want to parse a language with nested expressions, which is tantamount to parsing markup in many ways. Regex is not the right tool for this. You should consider implementing your own parser.

Comment: @Mena Yep will definitely define a function for that. However, is there a possible way to get out the conditions of this string?

Comment: it is tricky with regex because you're looking at nested statements in parenthesis. I'll write an answer to get the main contents of the IF(...) conditions for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on the comments, if you want the main contents of the `IF(...)` conditions wherein the `...` is the content, here's a quick solution.

Please note that albeit this solution applies to the input at hand, it may be unreliable in other cases, with nested statements - basically it's a workaround.

```
String formula = "=IF(BI18=0;INT(YEAR(TODAY()));IF(INT(YEAR(BI18))>2025;2025;INT(YEAR(BI18))))";
//                            | positive lookbehind: starts with "IF("
//                            |        | any character, reluctantly quantified
//                            |        |  | positive lookahead, followed by 
//                            |        |  | ")", then...
//                            |        |  |     | ";" or end of input
//                            |        |  |     | 
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=IF\\().+?(?=\\)(;|$))");
Matcher m = p.matcher(formula);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

**Output**

```
BI18=0;INT(YEAR(TODAY())
INT(YEAR(BI18))>2025;2025;INT(YEAR(BI18)))
```

Comment: Wow thx for your answer! As I understand it, you basically track parenthesis in the statement. If you track parenthesis, I cannot think of a case where this cannot be possible. Any suggestion for  non possible cases?

Comment: @Kare you're welcome. Cases where this is not feasible would include anything with nested or malformed parenthesis. That's the same limitation regex would have with markup.

Comment: Thx for your reply! The thing is I am getting this excel formulas not broken so they cannot be malformed. However, I think some of them could be nested, so do you mean by nested parenthesis sth. like this: `AND(ROUND($GX18-SUM(0)/$M$12;2)<=0;$AK$7=1)`

Comment: @Kare precisely. You could, of course, recurse the match, but this might come with a cost both in terms of reliability and performance. **Edit** and it would be very hard to generalize the pattern well enough to be able to recurse.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex. In the [demo](http://regex101.com/r/tQ2dQ2), make sure to look at the capture groups on the right.

```
^=([^(]+)\(|\G([^;]+)[;|)$]
```

We retrieve the matches from capture Groups 1 and 2.

In Java, this means something like this:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^=([^(]+)\\(|\\G([^;]+)[;|)$]");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(your_original_string);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
  // check Group 1, which is regexMatcher.group(1)
  // check Group 2, which is regexMatcher.group(2)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
String str1 = "=IF(BI18=0;INT(YEAR(TODAY()));IF(INT(YEAR(BI18))>2025;2025;INT(YEAR(BI18))))";

ArrayList<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();

for(String str2 : str1.replaceFirst("=", "").split(";")){
    if(str2.contains("IF")){
        strList.add("IF");
        strList.add(str2.replaceAll("IF|\\(|\\)", ""));
    }else{
        strList.add(str2.replaceAll("\\(|\\)", ""));
    }   
}

System.out.println(strList.toString());
```

Output:

```
[IF, BI18=0, INTYEARTODAY, IF, INTYEARBI18>2025, 2025, INTYEARBI18]
```